# How can I change text in a large number PDFs?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have about 100 PDF files that each contain a string of text that needs to be replaced. This is to fix a typographical error that was repeated all over the place. Is there any tool or techniques I can use for doing this string replacement as a batch process across all the files, rather than updating each file one at a time, using Acrobat Pro?

Comment: It would be better to go back to the source documents, most likely.

Comment: Indeed it would, but these documents are years old, and the original sources cannot be located.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the trial version of [A-PDF Text Replace](http://www.windows7download.com/win7-a-pdf-text-replace/opwurnju.html) to do a batch replacement job.

[image]

Comment: This is a good option, except the trial version of this product ads a watermark to the PDFs that it updates. I don't mind paying the $27 for the registered version, although jumping through the hoops to get my organization to approve a $27 expenditure is another matter entirely...

Comment: This is the only solution I could find and unfortunately it's not freeware. Sorry...

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution would be to:
1) Merge the individual PDFs into one PDF using Acrobat Pro.
2) Convert that one PDF into a word file (save -as function in Acrobat Pro). 
3) Use MS Office to find and replace the text.
4) Convert the PDF back into a PDF file.  There is a plug-in for MS Office 2007 and above for this ( http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041 ).  Also you could install a PDF print driver and then print the word doc to a PDF file.  Bullzip ( http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php ) is just one free utility. 
5) Then split the one PDF into individual PDFs using the split function in Acrobat Pro.

Note:  If the original PDF's are images of the text (ie scanned and not converted to text by OCR) then this would not work.